# R programming + Making POST Json request of Https

Tags: json, r, curl

I need to make HTTPS POST request using R program to upload a JSON data into Splunk.

I am exploring curl library for same but getting error in executing simple GET call over HTTPS .. It makes me feel that may be curl doesn't provide support to HTTPS request..

Rstudio: Version 1.0.136
R :   3.3.2
curl: version 2.3

==============================================
sample code :

```
library(curl)
request <- curl_fetch_memory("https://httpbin.org/get")

Error : Error in curl_fetch_memory("https://httpbin.org/get") : 
        Failure when receiving data from the peer

however, i the similar GET request for http endpoint works pretty fine.
i.e. request <- curl_fetch_memory("http://httpbin.org/get")
```

Answer (score 1):

the `httr` library can be used for GETting and POSTing to API end points

```
library(httr)

httr::GET("https://httpbin.org/get")

# Response [https://httpbin.org/get]
# Date: 2017-06-27 05:24
# Status: 200
# Content-Type: application/json
# Size: 326 B
# {
#   "args": {}, 
#   "headers": {
#       "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
#       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
#       "Connection": "close", 
#       "Host": "httpbin.org", 
#       "User-Agent": "libcurl/7.51.0 r-curl/2.5 httr/1.2.1"
#   }, 
#   "origin": "45.126.44.231", 
#   ...
```

Similarly, there's a `httr::POST` function for POSTing.

An example POST would look like

```
requestBody <- paste0('{ 
"foo" : [ 
  {"id" : "myId", 
  "values" : {"a" : "b"}
  } 
 ] 
}')

res <- httr::POST(url = url,
                  httr::add_headers('Content-Type' = 'application/json'),
                  httr::add_headers('Accept' = 'application/json'),
                  httr::add_headers('X-Application-Id' = appId),
                  httr::add_headers('X-Api-Key' = apiKey),
                  body = requestBody,
                  encode = "json")
```

Comment: i have tried this open too.. but some how i am able to hit http GET request  i.e [httr::GET("http://httpbin.org/get")] but not https GET.

Comment: for https GET i am getting error : 
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached..

is it related to Proxy Setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to make https call to work in R.

as presumed, it was issue with Corporate proxy that was impacting https traffic and not http.

Here are the steps i performed.. thanks to the post : http://blog.csdn.net/wangishero/article/details/50859670

```
a) in Rstudio, go to "Tools --> Global Options --> Packages " . Uncheck the option "User Internet Explorer library/proxy for http"

b) # load httr library
library(httr)

c) # set proxy configuration
set_config(use_proxy(url="<corporate proxy>",port=<port>, username="<username>", password="<ur pwd>"))

d) # this is to prevent SSL warning
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

now i can execute Https request without any issue.